# How to say "stalker" ("prowler") in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request

How does one say "stalker" in Latin? In the sense of, as the [*OED*](https://oed.com/view/Entry/188828?redirectedFrom=stalker#eid20772228) puts it, "one who follows or harasses someone (often a public figure) with whom he or she has become obsessed."

Comment: IIRC, in one of his letters to Brutus, Cicero complains that, being a candidate, he's  followed by a crowd of hired youngsters loudly defaming him every time he walks the streets. I can't remember which letter it was, sorry. I'm on a limb that this was in a letter to Brutus, or even that it was Cicero :(

Answer (score 3):

In *Pro Fonteio*, 20(44) Cicero uses two verbs in one sentence: of pursuing or threateningly advancing, **instō, -āre**, and pressing on or threatening by proximity, **urgeō, urgēre, ursi** (*infero* is also related here, but wouldn't be specific enough out of context):

> infestis prope signis inferuntur Galli in M. Fonteium et **instant** atque **urgent** summo cum studio, summa cum audacia.

Literal: “Carrying unequivocally hostile standards, Gauls [push/attack/advance on] M. Fonteius and [**threaten/advancing on**] him and [**pursue/follow on heels of**] him with the most zeal, and the most audacity [possible/imaginable].”

[[ **commentary**: *infestis … signis* is an Abl. Abs.; *inferuntur* is not passive but rather medial in this context, which had reified in many daughter IE languages into a single mediopassive verb aspect; the current thinking is that PIE did not have a past tense proper, exactly like the most ancient Hittite and the most modern Russian don't, and got by the aspectual use of verb form, as we see here. ]]

My feeling is, if you're looking for a classical word for your translation, the verb *instō* is the best. It does not have an attested cognate noun, however. It's stem is *inste-* (despite PERF *institi*), because of its internal form (*in-* + *ste-*), with the stem sound change caused by the prefix (the process long ended and perceived as irregular by the Classical period). But neither **instetor* nor **instator* are attested as nouns.

If you go the former route, and *really* need a substantive (which I believe to rarely be an unavoidable case), consider nominalising the PresAP, *instans*, in your context. To me, it sounds the most fitting semantics for the the period the language was spoken by the highly-educated people.

Note that both the two verbs are wanting attested PP form. *urgeo* is also somewhat irregular. This cripples your chances of nominalising the verb w/o a ridiculous result.

---

TL;DR: Try to use the verb *instō* if you can do it at all, as Latin likes verbals much more than English (strung substantives like "End county freeway speed limit" is not good Latin); as the second choice, if substantiation is unavoidable, then a substantiated in context PresAP *instans*, which is still a verb form, although non-finite, is your second best choice.

Comment: L&S give the passive perfect *instatum*, and [it seems to be attested through future participles](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23instatu). I think *instator* sounds reasonable.

Comment: "instantatator" Do you mean *instator*? I'm not sure why you're deriving a new verb from the present participle.

Comment: @cmw Yes, I think you are probably right. I'll rewrite that part. It was a gut feeling, my bad.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, Reasonable, but unattested. I'm just not a fan of making new words in Classical Latin. Besides, English is very noun-heavy (a common joke goes "every noun can be verbed"). A road sign "End road work speed limit" has 5 words, all nouns. Latin, on the other hands, prefers verbs and finite verb forms to nouns. Yes, Cicero introduced many abstract nouns in _-io_, but I'm no Cicero, so I stick to attested words. :)

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: This is pidgin English ("End road work speed limiit."). It barely makes sense and people would laugh. An Indian, English-language, newspaper (2010), reporting a burglary: "Miscreants decamped with loot. They were nabbed by police-sleuths with dog-squad." It's accurate; tells the tale; but, I still laugh at it!

Comment: @tony I didn't make that comment. Pay attention to who you reply to!

Comment: @tony, Your profile says nothing about the country you live in, but this "pidgin English" is used on road sign across the whole US. Sanskrit is also quite often stringing nouns, by the way, and sometimes in such a quantity that would make out road signs blush. Nothing wrong with it. Attr. Adj and N. are very close categories, and English nearly uninflected, so they nearly merged in syntax. Also, a road sign must be designed such that this madcap going sixty in a metal box on rollers spent as little time as possible reading it...

Comment: @tony, and the heading you cite is a proper English dialect spoken in India. Everyone has an accent and speaks in a dialect. Yes, even you. Now you can have a second laugh! :))

Comment: @kkm: Sorry for mistaking you for Joonas. A dialect in one part of England will generate amusement in other parts of England. In London they say "Leave it out!", which means, "Stop being objectionable/ rude.", spoken as, "Leeeve it owwwwt.", "ow" as in "cow". Similarly, "You are having a laugh.", "You are making fun of someone/ something.", "Yooor 'avin a laaaarrff, aintcha?". Where "aintcha" = "aren't you". In London they mock the short vowels of the far North, e.g. "tart", here is "taaart", in the South.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Sorry.

Comment: @tony, ya good, dude, no biggie! :) The dialectal variety of England has always fascinated me. We're 4.5 times more English-first speakers peppered over 75 times the area, and come not even close to the difference between e.g. Estuary and Cumbrian. By the same measure of difference, I'd say we have AAVE, Southern, Boston and Everything Else. :)) AAVE is the most interesting linguistically: the first thing people notice is the sound system, but it's divergent even in its syntax. E.g., its verb/aspect system has one more verb tense, not found in any other US/UK English variety, AFAIK.

Comment: You mention Cicero, but what about Medieval Latin?

Comment: @Geremia, Not my cup of tea. A language without native speakers. But what about Elvish and Klingon?

Answer (score 2):

The verb "to stalk" has its origins in the world of hunting, "to stalk one's prey": the person or animal who secretes self, creeping silently behind cover, in pursuit of the target. It is easy to see how "stalking" acquired its contemporary, insidious connotation.

There may not be an exact equivalent, in Latin, when "stalking" (contemporary) would not have been seen as a crime.

There is e.g. "venator" = "hunter". A better fit may be "praedator", OLD, (masculine noun) = "prowler" (English-to-Latin section); in (Latin-to-English) plunderer, pillager; hunter. The "prowler" may have been the progenitor of "the stalker" but, although "praedator", reminiscent of the English "predator", sounds most appropriate it has more do do with thievery, in Latin, than the sexual perversion of an inadequate and/ or the malicious intent of an ex-partner. The "prowler", if memory serves could also be a night-time burglar/ thief, which parallels the Latin.

Interesting: I have not heard the term "prowler" for a long time. An old Oxford (English) dictionary (1979) does not list the contemporary meaning of "stalk". The nearest listing: "Pursue (enemy, game) stealthily".

EDIT: 28/5/2021

Whereas "praedator" may not go far enough, another term, which has resonance in English, may go too far: "pestis" (feminine noun) = "pest" (English-to-Latin). Supplementary meanings (Latin-to-English) = plague, pestilence; destruction, ruin, death.

In English, "pest" can mean anything from a naughty child to plagues of locusts devouring crops. It would be a mild term for a stalker. The latin, more apocalyptical, "ruin/ death", at least makes the point that sex-pests can be dangerous and sometimes kill their victims.